# Cluster point of a sequence with distinct elements

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

How to show that x is a cluster point of A iff there exist a sequence $a_n$ of distinct elements (that is $a_n \neq a_m$ for $m\neq n$) in A such that $a_n \rightarrow x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $X$ and let $x_0\in X$ be its cluster/limit point. By the definition for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $(B(x_0,\epsilon)\backslash\{x_0\})\cap A\neq\emptyset$ where $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ is the open ball around $x_0$ of radius $\epsilon$.

"$\Rightarrow$" We will construct a sequence $(a_n)$. Define $b_n$ to be any point of $(B(x_0,1/n)\backslash\{x_0\})\cap A$ which is nonempty by the assumption. Note that $d(b_n,x_0)\leq 1/n$ and so $b_n\to x_0$. Now this sequence may contain duplicates. So let's refine it:

$$a_1:=b_1$$
$$r_n:=\min\big\{m\in\mathbb{N}\ |\ b_m\not\in\{a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}\}\big\}$$
$$a_n:=b_{r_n}$$

Note that $r_n$ is well defined since $(b_n)$ is convergent and does not contain a constant subsequence. Also note that if $(b_n)$ is injective, then $r_n=n$ and so $a_n=b_n$. Either way $(a_n)$ is always injective and converges to $x_0$.

"$\Leftarrow$" Conversly, since $a_n\to x_0$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ there is $n$ such that $a_n\in B(x_0,\epsilon)$. Since $(a_n)$ is a sequence of distinct elements then $a_n\neq x_0$ for sufficienly large $n$. Thus WLOG we may assume that $a_n\in B(x_0,\epsilon)\backslash\{x_0\}$ which completes the proof.

Comment: did you mean $d(b_n,x)\leq 1/n$ and so $b_n\to x$ to be $d(b_n,x_0)\leq 1/n$ and so $b_n\to x_0$

Comment: Also can you please explain how did you arrive at the defination of $r_n$?

Comment: @Sakh10 $r_n$ is needed to formally define $a_n$ which supposed to be "first $b_m$ that didn't occure earlier". I want to get rid of potential duplicates. There was a mistake in the definition (it is supposed to be recursive). And yes, I meant "$x_0$". Fixed.